# Getting ID of image being resized using Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using Jquery UI to drag and drop and resize images. I am resizing the image within the div and dragging the Div to resolve the bug in Jquery UI if one drags and resizes div.

How do I find the div ID of the image being resized?

My code is as follows:

```
$("img").resizable({ handles:'n,e,s,w,ne,se,nw,sw' , maxHeight: 300, aspectRatio: true, 
stop:   function(event, ui) { alert( // want to send div ID of the image);} });
```

HTML code

```
  <div id="pic1" style="float:left"> <img src="image source" height="150"></div>
```

I already tried unsuccessfully to get div ID of the image
1. using ui.originalElement[0].attr('id'), ui.originalElement.attr('id')
2. using event.trigger.id

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')`?  "div ID of the image" doesn't make much sense.  What are you asking?

Comment: The image is contained within a div. I want to get the ID of the div. Due to a bug in Jquery UI, I cannot resize the div, but have to resize image instead. I want to find ID of the div for the image being resized. For example, in this case, I want "pic1" to be returned. $(this).attr('id') did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you were after

```
$(this).parent().attr('id')
```